# Colorscheme in Vim not working on initial boot up

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Let me preface by saying that I am entirely new to Vim and MacVim.  I am trying to get my preferred colorscheme to work, and I have been partially successful.  As it currently stands, the colorscheme will work if, once I edit into a file I type:

```
:syntax enable
```

However, on the intial load up, it does not work.  I thought by putting syntax enable in my .vimrc file, that would activate it at load up, but this apparently is not working.  So far, my .vimrc files looks like:

```
set nocompatible                                "We want the latest Vim settings/options

so ~/.vim/plugins.vim

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start                  "Make backspace behave like every other editor.
let mapleader = ','                             "The default leader is \, but a comma is much better.
set number                                      "Activates line numbering.

"-----------Visuals------------"
colorscheme atom-dark                       "Sets colorscheme.
set t_CO=256                                "Use 256 colors.  This is useful for terminal Vim.
set guifont=Fira_Code:h13                   "Sets font and font height.
set linespace=15                            "Macvim-specific line height.

set guioptions-=l                       "Removes left hand scroll bar.
set guioptions-=L                       "Removes left hand scroll bar on vertically split screens.
set guioptions-=r                       "Removes right hand scroll bar.
set guioptions-=R                       "Removes right hand scroll bar on vertically split screens.
```

There is some more to it, but I don't believe it's relevant.  Also, I have the colorscheme saved in my ~/.vim/colors folder, if that matters. And, finally, I am using MacVim for the most part.

What am I missing to get the colorscheme to work on the initial load?  Or is it just required that I always manually enable syntax each time?

Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT**

My .gvimrc file:

```
 set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
 filetype off                  " required
 set modelines=0              " sets modeline to 0 for security



 " Turn on line numbers
 set number
```

Comment: Do you have `.gvimrc`? It's possible that `.gvimrc` or the system's gvimrc affects the settings from `.vimrc`.

Comment: Is it safe to remove .gvimrc?  Would it solve the problem if I did?

Comment: Can you provide the content of `.gvimrc`?

Comment: Added it to my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `filetype off` from your `.gvimrc`. First, see `:help gvimrc`:

> The gvimrc file is where GUI-specific startup commands should be placed. It is always sourced after the vimrc file. If you have one then the $MYGVIMRC environment variable has its name.

Your `.vimrc` file sets `filetype plugin indent on`. But `.gvimrc` will be sourced *after* the `.vimrc` file, and it sets `filetype off` again. So any filetype detection will not be performed within your MacVim.

Also I recommend you to make `.gvimrc` contain GUI-specific configurations only. This means you can remove

```
set compatible
filetype off
set number
```

from your `.gvimrc`. Also you can move `set modelines=0` to `.vimrc`, but I don't think it's necessary, so you may remove it also.

Additionally, you have options which will only work with GUI enabled Vim such as `guifont`, `linespace` and `guioptions` in your `.vimrc`. To make your `.vimrc` work on terminal Vim too, wrap that options with `if has('gui_running')`. So the `.vimrc` would be:

```
set nocompatible                                "We want the latest Vim settings/options

so ~/.vim/plugins.vim

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set backspace=indent,eol,start                  "Make backspace behave like every other editor.
let mapleader = ','                             "The default leader is \, but a comma is much better.
set number                                      "Activates line numbering.

"-----------Visuals------------"
colorscheme atom-dark                       "Sets colorscheme.
set t_Co=256                                "Use 256 colors.  This is useful for terminal Vim.

if has('gui_running')
  set guifont=Fira_Code:h13               "Sets font and font height.
  set linespace=15                        "Macvim-specific line height.

  set guioptions-=l                       "Removes left hand scroll bar.
  set guioptions-=L                       "Removes left hand scroll bar on vertically split screens.
  set guioptions-=r                       "Removes right hand scroll bar.
  set guioptions-=R                       "Removes right hand scroll bar on vertically split screens.
endif
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and very helpful.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score -2):

First, you mistyped `t_CO`; it's `t_Co`.

Second, that line is completely useless. Remove it and configure your terminal emulator correctly instead.

Third, `colorscheme atom-dark` will only work in the MacVim GUI. If you want `atom-dark` to work in Vim you'll need to use the `atom-dark-256` variant. Note that `atom-dark-256` is machine-generated so there will probably be *many* differences between `Vim` and `MacVim`.

Four, use [the project's issue tracker](https://github.com/gosukiwi/vim-atom-dark/issues).

Comment: Points 1 and 2 could have been combined, and point 1 could have been left out completely.  For point 3, I mentioned in my question that I am using MacVim, so I'm unsure of why you included it at all.  And the link on point 4 points to an issue tracker that does not contain any relevant information for my question (as far as I can see), at least.  Either way, the question still stands.  Thanks.

Comment: The issue tracker is for you to *use*.